# Simple program that adds numbers from user

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to write a simple program that uses scanf to input 5 numbers from the user and add them together. Here is the code I have so far..

```
  int main()   
    {

    int i;  
    int j=1;  
    int k=1;

            for (i=1; i<= 5; i++)
            {
                  scanf("%d\n", &j);
                  k = k+j;
            }   
            printf("%d\n", k);
    }
```

But here's what happens when I run the program:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
5  
16
```

Basically, it asks me for a sixth number (obviously, I just need 5), and it also adds one to the final result. (1+2+3+4+5=15).

Any thoughts on this. Am I making a simple mistake somewhere?

Comment: You're starting with `k=1`, not `k=0`.

Comment: Why are you adding a newline to the `scanf` call?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be initializing k (which is the number you hold your sum in) as one, then adding all the other numbers to it. Try this:

```
int k = 0;
```

instead.

Then, when you do
    k = k+j

the first time, k will be 0, and not 1. You also don't need to do j=1.

That said, you can also use a shortcut for k = k +j;

```
k += j;
```

C programmers have to do this pattern so much that they built a shortcut into the language specifically for it.

In your for loop, it's convention in C to start at zero and work to < your max number, as well:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

I'm not sure why it's asking an extra time, but try setting your loop as that and seeing if it works.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you are initializing `k` incorrectly, but I suspect that what's causing your problem is that you are using `scanf("%d\n", &j);` instead of `scanf("%d", &j);`. `scanf()` ignores whitespace leading up to the match.

Answer (score 1):

Initially `k = 1`. Then you add the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` to it. Altogether they sum up to `1+1+2+3+4+5`, which is `16`.

You should generally think about initializing variables.

- `i` doesn't need to be initialized before the `for` loop.
- `j` doesn't need to be initialized, since it will be read from the input.
- `k` needs to be properly initialized. But since it has a certain purpose you should rather call it `sum` than `k`. And when you sum up things, you should start with `0`.

Additionally you should check whether the call to `scanf` was successful. In that case the function returns `1`.

```
if (scanf("%d", &j) == 1) {
  sum += j;
} else {
  fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
  break; /* exit the for loop. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, k initialized at 0 and doing a scanf input without the \n which is an endline :

```
int main() {
    int i;  
    int j=0;  
    int k=0;
    for (i=1; i<= 5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &j);
        k = k+j;
    }   
    printf("%d\n", k);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: No. There is no 6th iteration. The additional `1` was in the `k` from the moment where the program says `int k = 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

The '\n' character is unnecessary. I suspect you are mixing up your printf and scanf syntax :P